# What are the other "first cognitive tools" beside analogy?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

In the paper [The Analogical Paradox: Why Analogy Is So Easy In Naturalistic Settings, Yet So Difficult In The Psychological Laborator](http://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/~dunbarlab/pubpdfs/dunbarAnal2000.pdf), Dunbar says:

> Analogy is one of the first cognitive tools that they use when reasoning about  these  unexpected findings.

Some other authors would argue that [analogy is the core of *all* thinking](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7711871-surfaces-and-essences). But anyway, what are the other "first cognitive tools" that we have?